# Laravel call all attributes at once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

How can I call *all* of my models attributes including the ones defined as accessors/mutators?

At the moment I am creating accessors/mutators like;

```
public function setSatisfiedWithQualityOfCourseAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['group_answers']['satisfied_with_quality_of_course'] = $value;
}

public function getSatisfiedWithQualityOfCourseAttribute()
{
    if (isset($this->group_answers['satisfied_with_quality_of_course'])) {
        return $this->group_answers['satisfied_with_quality_of_course'];
    }

    return null;
}
```

And I can call them from my controller with something like `$response->satisfied_with_quality_of_course` but I need to be able to return all of them without explicitly calling them one at a time. Can I do that?

I need to call all "real" attributes and all "accessors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$response->attributesToArray()` to get an array of all attributes, including your custom accessors.

You can use `$response->toArray()` to get loaded relationships as well, with their attributes.

If your custom accessors define new pseudo attributes (as opposed to overwriting existing database columns) you should also add them to the `$appends` array.

```
protected $appends = ['satisfied_with_quality_of_course'];
```

Comment: If I don't have an already selected model, example `$responses = Response::all();` - how can I get list of all the attribute keys?

Comment: @mike3875 You asked how to call all attributes. You do that after you have a particular model loaded. Most of your attributes will be coming from database columns, which means you need a database records loaded first! Why in the world would your controller be working with a Model class without a record loaded?

Comment: In this case, I am about to export everything to a CSV. At the moment I am using `\Schema::getColumnListing('responses')` but that will not include all my accessors

Comment: @mike3875 you really should have included that in your original question. =) the short answer is still to pull the first real record from your DB, then use `$response->attributesToArray()` to figured out your CSV headings. assuming you have a loop of some kind, just do this in the very first loop iteration.

Comment: You did answer my original question though. And I will be using that suggested method, thank you.

Comment: That's a fair response. I wonder if there could be an issue if the first response in the table has not answered every question. I will try it out and see.

Comment: @mike3875 That won't be a problem. Eloquent will have all the columns, even the ones with empty/null values. So you can use `array_keys($response->attributesToArray())` to get your list of headers. Then probably remove underscores and convert the text to uppercase for each one?